# How Many is "A Few"?

Tags: phrases, semantics

I'm preparing some marketing materials for my boss, and one section contains the phrase "Here are a few examples:". The list that follows contains two items, which strikes me as being incorrect, though I can't find much evidence of this.

Is it semantically correct to refer to two items as "a few"? Is there a solid rule for this, or is it just personal preference?

**Edit -** As Armen correctly pointed out, this question is about semantics rather than grammar. I changed my phrasing to reflect this.

Comment: It is certainly *grammatically* correct. Your question is about semantics.

Comment: My personal preference is for "a few" to be at least three.  I don't always use it this way, though, because I use "a few" for small indeterminate numbers, and I don't always know at speech time whether that number will turn out to be three or greater.

Comment: *Here are two examples:*?

Comment: "A few" is exactly four. Always. If you use it for anything else, you are wrong. If you take it to mean something else, you are wrong.

Comment: 'Many' being 'two or over' in mathsspeak is going to bring down Reg's new regime. And 'fewer than' now sounds fun.

Comment: "A couple" is two; "a few" is three, four, or five; and "several" is six or seven.

Comment: So "many" is 8 or more?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For two I mostly use *some*
Like snailboat said, *a few* sounds like 3 or more.
It is not grammatically incorrect though. It's simply what one thinks sounds better.